# Templating static Create function

Tags: c++

I have following base class:

```
class Base abstract
{
public:
   virtual ~Base() {};

protected:
   Base() {};

   virtual bool Initialize() abstract;
};
```

In extending classes that are not abstract I always define static Create function.

```
class Next : public Base
{
public:
   static Next* Create(/*eventual params*/);

   ~Next() {};

protected:
   Next(/*eventual params*/) {};

   virtual bool Initialize() {/*...*/};
};
```

Create function looks **always** like this:

```
Next* Next::Create(/*eventual params*/)
{
   bool succes;

   Next* next = new Next(/*eventual params - same as above*/);
   succes = next->Initialize();
   if(!succes)
   {
      return NULL;
   }

   return next;
}
```

My question is; is it possible to shorten this function down? Using template for example or closing it in one line?

Comment: You have a memory leak if `Initialize()` fails....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using templates in a function to create a generic class and call some function in it is simple, the problem you have is the `/*eventual params*/` part. You can solve that with something called [*parameter packs*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), also called [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).

Perhaps something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename ...A>
T* create(A... args)
{
    T* object = new T(std::forward<A>(args)...);
    if (object->Initialize())
        return object;

    delete object;
    return nullptr;
}
```

With your example class `Next` can be used like

```
Base* pointer_to_next = create<Next>(/* eventual arguments */);
```

Of course, it requires C++11.

Comment: and you can't access the private constructor from the free function, so you need to add a friend declaration.